# Is there a way to mark a question as not being a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

So I was writing an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66974377/why-am-i-not-getting-re-declaration-error-in-global-scope) explaining where identifiers can be re-declared and I click post but nothing happens - turns out someone marked the question as duplicate.

I don't think this question is a duplicate since it's asking for when an identifier can be redeclared and this has nothing to do with "tentative definition" directly but rather more with linkage of identifiers.

Anyway my original point is what to do in my case when the question is already marked as a duplicate but I don't think it's a duplicate - can I somehow mark it as a non-duplicate so I can finish writing my answer.

Comment: Once you have enough rep you can opt to reopen it, but otherwise there's nothing more to do. In this case the OP approved the closure, so there's no real reason to continue.

Comment: If you see a chance to edit the question yourself, to make it clearer (without laying words in OP's mouth, or changing the intend of the question), your edit will bump the question to the reopen queue. In such case it's also good etiquette, to point out your edits and disagreement with the dupe closure in a comment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think the question (that this topic was created based on) is clear enough in its current form.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions let's think logically. If the question is clear enough in its current form, then it wouldn't have been marked as a duplicate. It was. Therefore, it's *not* clear enough in its current form. I'm also far from an expert in C but "whatever that tentative definition is" seems like exactly what's happening. I've just read the duplicate and it seems applicable. So, if you think it *isn't* it's definitely not clear *to me* why you think that way. Both the existing answers seem to refer to exactly the same concept, too.

Comment: i fail to see how the duplicate could be not a duplicate of this, though i'll admit my knowledge of that language is lacking. Even the answers seem to be saying *exactly* the same thing, including the one the OP accepted.

Comment: @VLAZ Tentative definition is not linkage. If you have read the standard you would know. But that's besides the point - my question is how can we rely on the OP to assure us that the question is in fact duplicate considering the fact that he is the one asking and thus lacking knowledge.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions I've not read the standard, yes. I don't feel the need to do that in order to understand why you think tentative definition is not applicable. But I've no horse in this race. If you think the question is absolutely clear, and *not* a duplicate, *and* you don't want to do anything to make it any clearer then your only other (short term) option is to just wait until maybe somebody else initiates the process of reopening. Your long-term goal can be to get a gold badge and reopen the question immediately. Take your pick.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm not that invested either. Just wanted to point out some flaws in the system since you know there is the rule when a question has answers and such it can't be deleted and so but here I am not even allowed to post to what may be a valid question. That doesn't mean this question is not 100% incorrectly marked as a duplicate - what I'm saying is simply that I couldn't care less.  I'm not gonna bother fighting over C on the site called meta to help this specific case. If you know something and want to fight there is a chat called C - you can post there.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm not asking about my own question.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions - the same guidance applies to arguing about questions of others. Vote (flag for now, but you will soon be able to vote yourself) to reopen if you think this is not a duplicate, explain why do you think other answers are inapplicable (you know, just as what Makoto said below), hence the vote for dupe closure.

Comment: @OlegValter I've edited my title.

Comment: Please don't edit the title, or the question, in a way that invalidates existing answers. You can go ahead and post a new question if you want.

Comment: @cigien OK - i'll sorry.

Answer (score 8):

No, not really.

Once a question is closed as a dupe, that's usually the end of the story - an answer is found somewhere else.

It's kinda compounded because *the OP* closed this as a dupe on their own (through the Community user), and reopening the question just so you could finish answering the question kinda goes counter to what the OP thought/believed worked for them.

[image]

If you don't think that the question is suitably answered by the dupe, you can vote for the question to be reopened once you hit 3K reputation, or you can explain here on Meta why you don't believe the question was a suitable duplicate and let others in the community weigh in.

Comment: Yeah but is the OP knowledgeable enough to know if the answer is a dupe considering the fact that he is the one asking (and thus lacking knowledge).

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions:  It's not my place to guess that.  Best advice I can give you is to let this one go and move on; being frustrated or questioning if the OP actually gets help from the duplicate closure that they themselves finalized is only an exercise in frustration, and you're not going to be getting anywhere with that.

Comment: I'm not frustrated. But it seems you are for some reason. I'm just asking a question.

Comment: I just thought I had a valid point to ask - especially since I was not able to post an answer which may also be valid and not a duplicate.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions:  You had a valid point, but the answer is effectively ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ because the OP decided not to contest the dupe closure (which is normally what happens), and there's not a whole lot of evidence being provided that the dupe isn't suitable.  While you have a point, there's not much of a follow-up, so there's not much else to discuss on it, really.

Comment: The discussion may be is the OP knowledgeable enough to take that decision on their own. Maybe don't even ask them at the first place if that would mean that other users can't answer the question after. If we trust that much the person giving the duplicate flags - why trust some random user posting the question with that potentially destructive decision.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions - They certainly know if the answers to the duplicate question addresses their question or not.  Since the question is closed as a duplicate, and you wanted to answer the author's question, just answer the duplicate.