# Can we trust the OP to decide if a question is a duplicate or not?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

Once a question is accepted as a duplicated by the OP you can't post any more answers to it and we are trusting the OP with that potentially impactful (to new answer writers) action.

How come some random user can single-handedly accept a question to be a duplicate from a single vote - are they knowledgeable enough? What about the hard work of other writers?

I suggest disabling this feature and only marking as duplicate when enough votes from credible users are cast or if a user with high enough rep with the tag decides to close it (as it is right now). I'm talking about the original poster who should be forbidden from taking that action all by themselves.

Comment: A gold badge in  tag comes at 1000 score in that tag and 200 answers in that tag. If that is not knowledgeable, I don't know what is.

Comment: @rene I'm talking about OP accepting a duplicate of it's own question.

Comment: @rene that’s 10k rep (1000 accumulated score), isn’t it?

Comment: Oh, so? What is the problem? An OP follows a dupe suggestion because an answer on the dupe solves their problem. How is that bad?

Comment: Relevant: [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: @rene He is the one asking - how can he know if that question solves their problem.

Comment: @yivi yeah, it is score, so 10K rep.

Comment: .... How can you know it *doesn't*? I say "I have this issue" I get a helpful banner asking me "is this helping you?". I click yes. And now... I'm wrong?

Comment: Because they have the problem in the first place and will likely have tried it out?

Comment: In 103 points you’ll be able to vote to reopen. Just be patient.

Comment: @Patrice Yeah but that comes from a single flag and may be misleading.

Comment: I may bloody hope if you ask the question that you're competent to judge that my question is answered. Who are you to decide I need a different answer? I just solved my problem with the dupe.

Comment: @rene You may have thought so but actually in reality deleted your whole server.

Comment: So you are saying the OP must have accepted the dupe before testing it to make sure it works? There is no chance they hit the link, copied the code, ran it, got the right result, _then_ OK'd the dupe?

Comment: Don't pretend you know better then the OP. It is the same with accept votes. It is not our business to judge, let alone overrule.

Comment: This is a valid question, but note that many regulars on Meta are also active curators of content on the site. As such, the focus is on closing posts (which is a good thing, there's lots of content that needs to be closed), and so we trust the OP pretty much only when it's convenient. So if OP accepts the dupe suggestion, we trust them to make that decision, but if they reject the dupe suggestion, we don't trust them, and will happily close the post anyway. Basically, any feature request that makes curation any harder is not going to get you much support, unless you have a very strong case.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions a single flag.... from the person who ASKED THE QUESTION. I mean.... "did this solve your issue". *OP presses yes* System: **WRONG!**  There is a point to be made about "Op didn't know enough to realize this isn't what he needs". But then... I'd argue the duplicate offered is indeed wrong, but the question needs to be clarified.

Comment: @Patrice Just don't ask them. Only warn them. Let the moderators close the question or if it gets enough flags. In the meantime they may choice to edit their post or upvote the dup.

Comment: If you are worried about losing the answer, just copy the answer to the duplicate, since it will likely answer it too. If not, ask your own non-duplicate question and self-answer it with you answer.

Comment: Same logic would suggest that the thousands of visitors every day that come here from search engines, or on site search, can't be trusted either to solve their own issues by reading other questions/answers.

Comment: @charlietfl Well if questions are marked as duplicates willy-nilly like that I wouldn't doubt so.

Comment: @cigien The thing is, OP wants their question answered. So when they accept a duplicate, it's fairly safe to assume that it actually answered their question. On the other hand, if they reject a duplicate, it may mean it doesn't actually answer their question, but more often it means they didn't spend enough time reading it to realize it's fundamentally the same thing or they just want to be spoonfed something they can copy+paste. There's no incentive for them to accept an invalid dupe the way there is to reject a valid one.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yes, I certainly agree that an OP is much more likely to reject a valid dupe than accept an incorrect one. It does happen though; I've seen OPs incorrectly accept a dupe that looks right, only to discover that it doesn't actually solve their problem, and then they just ask another question because they can't change their decision. I guess I was placing too much emphasis on what benefits the curators when I said "only when it's convenient"; it is better to let the OP accept rather than reject a suggestion.

Comment: Note that we trust the OP by default, but other users can still vote to reopen the question if they think the duplicate is a mistake. This is a clear contrast from accepted answers, where other users are not able to do anything if the wrong answer got accepted.

Comment: As different as the OP's opinion might be from the Meta consensus, this is a clear enough question. There is no reason to close it as unclear, let alone delete it.

Comment: I am also voting to reopen the question. I disagree with its premise (the OP is the person to decide whether or not the dupe target helped them), but the question itself is clear and comprehensible (which is also substantiated by the answers in the Q&A).

Answer (score 16):

Yes, we do trust OP to know if an answer indeed solves their problem. We do allow them to accept an answer in the original question or equally allow to accept that the duplicate contains the answer.

If OP is unable to verify that an answer solves their problem it is an unclear question and OP should have waited asking it in a first place.

If you believe that question is asking something else - feel free to ask new question and self-answer or edit original question to make it clear that it is not duplicate (also that would be clearly against OP intent and likely such edit should be rolled back).

Comment: What if the question is theoretical and now they've been taught wrong (if that flag was falsely).

Comment: To play the devils advocate: when SO trusts OPs to know when the question is a dupe, then why don't they trust them to know when a question is not a dupe and still allows the question to be closed, even if OP declined?

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions You still can write comments, even to OP.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions as Tom said you still can comment, bring up to meta (for specific-question rather than a policy question like this), edit, vote to re-open... If comment would contain plausible explanation why it is not duplicate it likely stop voting as duplicate in a first place. [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66974377/why-am-i-not-getting-re-declaration-error-in-global-scope#comment118386990_66974377) along the lines "This site populated by complete  idiots and only I have the TRUE ANSWER (tm)" are not really useful for that process so (even if worded nicely).

Comment: @Tom It looks plausible that the OP being mistaken is more likely to happen when they are arguing against duplicate closure than when they are arguing for it.

Comment: Should probably be noted that even questions closed as dupe are likely to be seen by knowledgeable users anyway, and that they can correct an erroneous duplicate link, single handedly for gold badge holders, or by voting to reopen for others. It happened to me a few times to change the dupe link + comment.

Answer (score 10):

> enough votes from credible users are risen.

Which incredible users might that be? Those who just managed to reach 3K and now happen to review random questions in the close vote queue. Pretty incredible.

"The elitism on Stack Overflow is so damn high." is an often heard complaint by users.

Blocking them from accepting a proposed duplicate on their **own** question is certainly not going to counter that criticism. Who do we think we are that three (3!) random internet strangers know better what solves a question than the OP.

Seriously.

The "hard work" of other writers can go on the duplicate. Assuming the answers are indeed an valuable addition to the existing answers on the duplicate. The closed question is a nice signpost so others can find the hard work of everyone in a canonical place. Instead of scattered around multiple questions.

Comment: And still my comment to the other answer applies here - although maybe fairly since I didn't include it in my original question - what if the question is asking for explanation and the given explanation as a duplicate is not the optimal. Not the answers in it but the question itself. I can't edit the other question just because I think it's not optimal to this quesiton.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions then the question is the problem, not your answer or the dupe. Fix the question.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the word incredible. https://wikidiff.com/uncredible/incredible

Comment: You are seeing this from the POV of someone active in the review queues (thanks for being btw). But I'd argue that it may also very well be the 3 most knowledgeable people in the subject matter from the question itself, if the tags are small enough to not have a gold badge hammer. And I'd even argue that for it to be in the close review queue, at least the first voter has to have at least some interest in that domain to go see the question in the first place. And yes, from my POV as answerer, I see askers are most of the time less knowledgeable than the ones posting answers.

Answer (score 5):

> So this question stems from the fact that once a question is accepted as a duplicated by the OP you can't post any more answers to it and we are trusting the OP with that potentially impactful (to new answer writers) action.

In the case of your most recent [example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406601/is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-question-as-not-being-a-duplicate) it was two knowledgeable users plus the author that determined it was a duplicate.  The two users who voted to close the question, combined have nearly 500 answers, to questions with the C and C++ tag.

> How comes some random user can single handedly accept a question to be a duplicate from a single vote - is he knowledgeable enough - what about the hard work of other writers?

The random user you speak of was the actual author of the question.  Had this user not agreed with both of those other users, the close vote would have stood, until additional users voted to close the question.

> I suggest to disable this feature and only mark as duplicate when enough votes from credible users are risen.

If we allow an author of a question to accept an answer, even if it's a bad answer, we should also accept when they agree it's a duplicate of an existing question.

> Or I mean if the user with high enough rep with the tag decides to close it (as its right now). I'm talking about the original poster whom should be forbidden from taking that action all by himself.

I strongly disagree with this suggestion.  The author of the question is the next best individual to determine, if an answer to another question, addresses their question.  **In this case not only did multiple community users agree it was a duplicate but the author also agreed.**

> a single flag.... from the person who ASKED THE QUESTION. I mean.... "did this solve your issue".

Except a single flag, wouldn't actually close a question, unless you are talking about a user with a gold badge in a tag.

Comment: I used the example question, due to the author's [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406601/is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-question-as-not-being-a-duplicate) question, since using a real example makes this an easier question to answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you replace one phrase in this question, it looks kinda silly...

> How comes some random user can single handedly accept [an answer] - is he knowledgeable enough - what about the hard work of other writers?

...because we *already* trust users to accept an answer, so then why shouldn't we trust that same user to close their question as a duplicate of another question?

The answer to both of these is similar: it's about **what works best for the OP**.  If there are other answers, great - people can read them.  If the OP closed their question as a duplicate faster than other answers could be filled in, **that's great too** as it means that we reduce the likelihood of duplicate info across multiple answers, which makes it harder for others to find an answer.

Comment: Well don't mind them do but the thing with the close votes is impactful to the other creators and the OP may not be knowledgeable enough to take that decision not only for themselves but for others too. Others which may want to contribute good to this site and are unable to because of the rightfully so lack of knowledge from the question author.

Comment: Is the dupe closed?  Post your answer *there* if it's still good enough or not otherwise covered anywhere else.